# for i in nli: if i not in fli: f=True as comprehension

Tags: for-comprehension

How to convert this piece of code in python3 to comprehension?
Im trying to access each element of list1 compare it with list2,if not in it then flag is set.
Please help:

for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        flag=True

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `any` function. This functions takes an iterable over booleans (or expressions convertible into booleans) and returns `True` if and only if any of the elements in the iterable are true.

```
flag = any(i not in list2 for i in list1)
```

That is: Go through `list1` and check for each element `i` whether it is *not* in `list2`. If this is `True` for any `i`, the `any` function will return `True`.

There is also the closely related function `all`. As you may suspect this returns `True` if *all* elements of the input iterable are `True`. You could also write the above as

```
flag = not all(i in list2 for i in list1)
```